# where is codeigniter handling the routes if there are no routes defined in routes.php

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, url, routes

I am taking over an existing codeigniter project and there are no routes defined in routes.php file.  But the website is indeed handling custom routes.

this is all there is in the routes file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

I'm on version 1.7.2

**EDIT**

```
<?php

/*



|---------------------------------------------------------------
| PHP ERROR REPORTING LEVEL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CI runs with error reporting set to ALL.  For security
| reasons you are encouraged to change this when your site goes live.
| For more info visit:  http://www.php.net/error_reporting
|
*/

    error_reporting(E_ALL); 

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
| Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
| as this file.
|
| NO TRAILING SLASH!
|
*/

    $system_folder = "system";

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
| folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder 
| can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.
| For more info please see the user guide:
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
|
|
| NO TRAILING SLASH!
|
*/
    $application_folder = "application";
    /*$application_folder = "workshopapplication";*/


/*
|===============================================================
| END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS
|===============================================================
*/


/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| SET THE SERVER PATH
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Let's attempt to determine the full-server path to the "system"
| folder in order to reduce the possibility of path problems.
| Note: We only attempt this if the user hasn't specified a 
| full server path.
|
*/
if (strpos($system_folder, '/') === FALSE)
{
    if (function_exists('realpath') AND @realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
    }
}
else
{
    // Swap directory separators to Unix style for consistency
    $system_folder = str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder); 
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| DEFINE APPLICATION CONSTANTS
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| EXT       - The file extension.  Typically ".php"
| SELF      - The name of THIS file (typically "index.php")
| FCPATH    - The full server path to THIS file
| BASEPATH  - The full server path to the "system" folder
| APPPATH   - The full server path to the "application" folder
|
*/
define('EXT', '.php');
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');

if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ($application_folder == '')
    {
        $application_folder = 'application';
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| LOAD THE FRONT CONTROLLER
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| And away we go...
|
*/
require_once BASEPATH.'codeigniter/CodeIgniter'.EXT;

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Comment: what is inside your `index` controller

Comment: check you loaded additional plugin,or any modification on core files.

Comment: routes.php does not contain the route list .. all controllers in you controllers directory are considered routes ..

Comment: In your default_controller put a controller name from application/controllers like `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";`

Comment: gives the apache's default not found page if index.php is omitted, otherwise it gives codeigniter's not found page.

Comment: @Demonyowh is this for old codeigniter versions?

Comment: well if it's not defined in your config/routes.php , consider all controllers as routes ..

Comment: @Demonyowh i didn't know this before about codeigniter, but your right.  ok that part is sorted out.  Can you put as answer ill check it off asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controllers are considered routes .. But you can also add routes in your config/routes.php

Comment: I just realized what's wrong with having the file locations/names and method names in the url, the directory structure is being exposed to the user.  This is a huge security problem.